# Why does Nexus 5 only allow up to 0.8 second exposure?

Tags: camera

Apparently with Lollipop it's possible to get more control of the camera. For example, it's possible to set the shutter speed. This does work, but only allows 0.8 seconds exposure on my Nexus 5, and apparently on some other phones you can choose a longer exposure time.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: What camera apps are you using? There's no shutter speed setting for stock Camera app.

Comment: I'm using Manual camera, Camera FV-5 and AZ camera.

Comment: Just researched a bit, and you're right about [other phones having longer exposure](http://www.camerafv5.com/pages/manual-camera-controls-table.php). Also, I found [this](https://github.com/PkmX/lcamera/issues/22). It seems that it's a "hardware limitation", or the limit that the system reports (set by manufacturer). However, I'm still not sure about the details.

Comment: Also, probably related from Photo.SE: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/why-are-there-limitations-to-the-upper-limit-of-exposure-time-in-digital-cameras